# How to check if header is exists or not in CSV file using CSVhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Recently I have migrated my CSVLibrary from 2.7.1 to 30 version.
With my old code, if the header is not there, It will not go into the IF condition so that hasHeaderRecord will be false. If the CSV file has a header, then it checks for header count.
But after upgrading if the CSV file did not have a header, it goes into the if condition which is not expected.

```
if (csvReader.Read())
    {
         var csvHeaders = csvReader.HeaderRecord;
         hasHeaderRecord = csvHeaders.Intersect(_Column).Count() == csvHeaders.Count();
    }
```

How to modify the piece of code after upgration.

Comment: Is that a typo, or did you really jump 28 versions ??

Comment: no. I upgraded CSVhelper libraries from 2.7.1 to latest version.

Comment: The old code could distinguish between a headerline and a dataline? Sounds like magic to me. How?

Comment: I'm not really seeing how the presence or absence of headers would impact the result of `csvReader.Read()`. That will (presumably, though I am guessing here) read the next line (whatever it is) or return some kind of EOF result if there is no next line. So I think there is not enough detail here to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your 2.7.1 code did go into the if statement even if there was no header. Your code `csvHeaders.Intersect(_ColumnNames).Count() == csvHeaders.Count()` is what you used to determine if there was a header.  The difference to version 30.0.1 is you have to manually read the header now.

Version 2.7.1 - Reads line and if no header, automatically tries to assign line to the header

```cs
csvReader.Read()
```

Version 30.0.1 - Reading the line and assigning the header has been split up. `Read()`, reads in the line. `ReadHeader()`, attempts to assign the read line to the header.

```cs
csvReader.Read()
csvReader.ReadHeader();
```

Possible upgrade of your code.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        BadDataFound = null
    };
    
    var _ColumnNames = new string[] {"Id","Name"};
    var hasHeaderRecord = false;

    using (var reader = new StringReader("1,name1\n2,name2"))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        if (csvReader.Read())
        {
            csvReader.ReadHeader();
            
            var csvHeaders = csvReader.HeaderRecord;            
            
            hasHeaderRecord = csvHeaders.Intersect(_ColumnNames).Count() == csvHeaders.Count();
            
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If CSV file did not have the header, in this case, csvReader.ReadHeader() throws BadDataException.

Comment: You didn't say that the first line could have bad data.  Does it work if you set `BadDataFound = null`?

Comment: CSV file may have a header (or) may not have a header as the first line. Header not present case, I got an exception as "CsvHelper.BadDataException: You can ignore bad data by setting BadDataFound to null.
IReader state:
   ColumnCount: 0
   CurrentIndex: -1
   HeaderRecord:

IParser state:
   ByteCount: 0
   CharCount: 414
   Row: 1
   RawRow: 1
   Count: 91
   RawRecord:"

Comment: If I have a file with no header and the first line is "1,name1".  Using `CsvReader.Read()` and `CsvReader.ReadHeader()`, I get a `HeaderRecord` of `{"1","name1"}` and `hasHeaderRecord  = false`.  You would need to create some sample code and sample data that fails.  It appears to work for me.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have completed all upgraded issues with your support. Thanks a lot for sharing your ideas